# Cannot receive another websocket message after interruption of thread with websocket session

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool, executorservice, spring-websocket

I have problem with receiving new messages from my JS client after I use the first received message in new thread and cancel the thread. I use spring boot for the back end. The interesting thing is that the session is not closed but I just cannot receive any more messages after the first one when I interrupt my thread.

Here is my websocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/socket1").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Here is my handler with the executor service:

```
public class WebSocketHandler extends AbstractWebSocketHandler {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketHandler.class);
    Test test = new Test();

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        logger.info("START");

        List<UrlWithPageNumber> listings = new ArrayList<>();
        listings.add(new UrlWithPageNumber( "www.somesite.com", 1));
        listings.add(new UrlWithPageNumber( "www.anothersite.com", 1));
        listings.add(new UrlWithPageNumber( "www.thirdsite.com", 1));
        checkItemsAsync(listings, session);

        logger.info("DONE");
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("DONE"));
    }


    public void checkItemsAsync(List<UrlWithPageNumber> listings, WebSocketSession session) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(listings.size());

        for (UrlWithPageNumber listing : listings) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                if(Test.stop) {
                    return;
                }

                ListingInfo listingInfo = test.itemPage(listing.getLink(), 1, 1);
                logger.info(listingInfo.toString());
                synchronized(session) {
                    try {
                        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(listingInfo.toString()));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                latch.countDown();

            });
        }
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is the following: I call my handleTextMessage method from JS client and the execution is starting then I press another button in my page and it is changing Test.stop boolean flag to true and in that way i stop the remaining threads to be executed. After that if I call handleTextMessage from the js like the first time it is not called. I checked if I close the WebSocketSession and then try to call the backend and the result is similar but in my case the session is not closed for sure ! The question is how to use the WebSocketSession many times and why the session is become broken when I use it in my executor service and stop the thread? Should I do something with the session if I shutdown threads or this is just some spring boot bug ?

Comment: In your example you don't need `CountDownLatch`. Are you sure that your code works below `latch.await();`?

Comment: yes thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the latch it wait more than expected because I skip some threads..